# SSIS excel source File values not transfered correctly

Tags: excel, types, ssis

I have an excel file (user input) and I want to append the data to another excel file.

I have 2 columns "Current Balance" and "Last Purchase" which both are amounts, float datatypes.

I created a data flow task with an excel source and an excel destination.

THE PROBLEM  is that for "Current Balance" the value of each cell is trasfered correctly but for "Last Purchase" the amount is transfered as it is displayed in the excel file and as the actual value.

an example :

for the following values as shown in excel

```
     Current Balance         Last Purchase
     6.137.736,73            
     15.634.073,28          
     15.015.015,02           15064084,69
     11.397.691,51
     24.764.305,42           23952682,99
```

this is how the ssis data viewer shows the values:

```
     Current Balance         Last Purchase
     6137736.7259
     15634073.28138
     15015015.0157           15064084,69
     ....
```

The expected values for the destination file should be:

```
       Current Balance         Last Purchase
       6137736.7259
       15634073.28138
       15015015.0157           15064084,684578
       ....
```

I dont have acess to the source excel file.
Is there any way to resolve this ? What if I use an scitp component to load the file ?

If any additional information is needed please ask for it.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: How should the Last Purchase values of "15064084,69" and "23952682,99" appear in the data viewer?

Comment: What data flow task is the data viewer associated with (or following)?  Perhaps it would help to show values as they appear in Excel source, then in the Excel destination, and finally what is expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I refreshed my question with the expected values. The data viewer is in between of the excel source and the excel destination. The problem is that for the first column the actual values are transfered , as expected, but for the second one are transfered the displayed values not the actual.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring data from Excel to your database with SSIS can be a tedious task.

When importing excel files with SSIS it will read the actual displayed value by default.

You can however override this by adding a hint to the connection string.

Add 'Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"' to your connection string and SSIS will read every cell as text when it imports the data.
This works for Excel 2007, 2010, 2013 (haven't tested 2016)

There is an alternative 'lazy' way to do it with **The mighty import wizard**:

Set the data types of all columns of your destination table to varchar.
Use **The mighty import wizard** when setting up the connection and classify all columns as text.

This should basicly achieve the same result